# How to get W10 allow unsigned legacy drivers in test mode?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-desktop

I'm playing around with unsigned but safe legacy drivers in W10. W10 won't allow you add unsigned drivers for security reasons but you can switch the system into the test mode which allows you to add the drivers.
The watermark is in down-right corner but I still can't add the driver.

Any suggestions ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by entering "advanced boot menu" and temporarily switching off "signed driver enforcement".